# Shell is trying to run /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh when opening

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I am pretty new to python (using Python 3.8.5 on MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2) + coding. I tried to make a virtual environment using pyenv but neither was successful. Now, when I open terminal  it says:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: /Users/frankiechiappetta/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/frankiechiappetta/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
```

**first:** I've tried to edit my bash_profile and when I run `echo $PATH` my path looks like this:

```
/Users/frankiechiappetta/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/frankiechiappetta/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:Library/Python/3.8/bin:
```

I've checked
`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` for "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" but I can't find it anywhere. I cannot find .pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh either.

**second:** I'm confused because my default shell is bash but for some reason every time I open terminal it says that my interactive shell is now zsh.

How do I edit my bash_profile so that this doesn't come up when opening terminal?  I don't even really know what is going on here so please excuse my novice-ness. I did a lot of research & troubleshooting today but nothing has worked thus far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possibly your solution is contained in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772925/bash-usr-bin-virtualenvwrapper-sh-no-such-file-or-directory Try to find the most recent approach in that discussion.

Comment: I tried all of those suggestions, unfortunately. I still cannot find either of those files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It might be related to the [recent switch](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208050) of MacOS from bash to zsh as the default login/interactive shell. Try to double-check the General settings of the terminal application itself. Also, you don't have to use anaconda or pyenv / virtualenvwrapper at all, to create virtual environments and code Python. Simply use Python's [built-in venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html): `python3 -m venv <new-env-name>` and then `source <new-env-name>/bin/activate` and `deactivate`. Hope it helps a bit!